# Reduce HTTP Requests in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have a Grails application that makes a lot of HTTP requests, because my application is loading different images on each GSP page.

I have many tags like the following on my page:

```
<img src="someurl">
```

How can I combine these requests to reduce the number of HTTP requests being sent? Is there a build in solution for Grails or a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use grails static resources to declare images http://www.grails.org/plugin/resources.

Because an image is a static resource though, the browser should be caching it and you should only suffer the performance hit the first time. Is that not happening?

Comment: I still use the <r:img> tag but nothing changes

Comment: Are you saying the browser isn't caching the image? That's not even a grails thing - that's just browser behavior for static resources.